# Honeywell Ck65 device with custom Camera app has darker image problems on android 10 verison?give suggestions

Tags: android-10.0

Its working fine in android 9 version Honeywell device.but,its have a problem in android 10 version honeywell device for customcamera app. camera preview having darkerissue.if any other devices having same problem ping me that.

Give any suggestions or solution for this problem.Thanks in advance